# Python, 'int' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python

```
data=0x00000
offset=0
bmp=open('victim.bmp','wb')
bmpheader=0 #will be filled later
for x in range(1,16777216): 
    bmp.seek(offset)    
    bmp.write(data)
    data=data+0x00001
    offset=offset+1
```

Here's a source, in which I try to make a programme which will fill a bmp file with hex values, like 00 00 00, 00 00 01, etc for 16 777 216 times. The error is in line 10 (bmp.write).

Comment: Look at the type of `0x000000`.  It is an `int`, not a byte string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `import struct` and then replace the bad line with

```
bmp.write(struct.pack('>I', data)[1:])
```

The `[1:]` is because there's no way to use `struct.pack` to make a 3-byte item, so it creates a (big-endian) 4-byte item and cuts off the first byte.

Also your `range` is one short and your `offset` logic is totally bogus and should be removed.

Comment: The other bad line which is not apparent is the initalization of data.

Comment: It creates file full of 01 02 03s, I want to make it to fill with 00 00 01, 00 00 02, 00 00 03 all the way to ff ff ff.